# text view not wrapping

Tags: android, textview

I just tried a sample of retrieving and passing it to a textview. 
I am having some trouble wrapping my textview. 
The bottom part is not completely shown.
What do i need to add to the xml file for it to completely show the bottom part of the data?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >




<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:maxLines = "1000"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ScrollView, set to fill_parent:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Comment: The last word is still cut in half, i don't have enough points to post my screenshot here.